# Cutting a string probability

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, geometric-probability

Suppose that I choose a point in a uniform random way on a string. The string is cut at that point. What is the probability that the larger piece of string is at least three times bigger than the smaller piece?

Using geometric probability, I'm not sure if the answer is $\frac{1}{4}$ or $\frac{1}{2}$.

I thought the answer may be that the point must lie in the left or right *quarter* of the string, giving a probability of $\dfrac 12$.

How do you do this problem and how do I arrive at the correct answer?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Can you edit your post to include what you have tried?

Comment: Done; I have made these edits. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: To emphasize... the question is asking the probability that the *larger piece* is at least $3$ times bigger than the smaller which does indeed have probability $\frac{1}{2}$.  The question is not asking the probability that the *left piece* is at least $3$ times bigger than the right piece which has probability $\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x<0.5$ be the shorter length, then the longer length is $1-x$.

$$1-x \ge 3x$$

which is equivalent to $$x \le \frac14$$.

The shorter length can be obtain from either side, that is suppose $y$ is the chosen point, we can either have $y \le 0.25$ or $y \ge 0.75$.

Hence the probability of interest is $\frac24=\frac12.$